# SOCI rowset<row> weird error

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, soci

I recently installed SOCI library for my project because it requires working with SQLite database.
I tried to fetch rowset but I got weird error:

```
"c:\mingw\include\soci\exchange-traits.h:35:5: error: incomplete type 'soci::details::exchange_traits<soci::row>' used in nested name specifier".
```

I have no idea what's wrong with my code... the line that does that error is:

```
soci::rowset<> results = (sql.prepare << "SELECT * from games where user_name='" << user.getName() << "'");
```

By the way, I use the most recent version of SOCI.
the wider part of the code:

```
soci::session& sql = conn.getSession();
soci::rowset<> results = (sql.prepare << "SELECT * from games where user_name='" << user.getName() << "'");
for(soci::rowset<>::const_iterator it = results.begin(); it != results.end(); ++it)...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the `soci::rowset` , because it's a templated type. So for example if you `select` a integer column, you would use a `soci::rowset<int>` as type for `results`. Your example is a special case, because you don't know the type yet, but for this soci has defined the `soci::row` type, so you could use `soci::rowset<soci::row> results`

Also you should never build your query by concatenation of user input strings, so instead of 
`sql.prepare << "SELECT * from games where user_name='" << user.getName() << "'"` use
`sql.prepare << "SELECT * from games where user_name=:name", soci::use(name,user.getName());` instead.

Otherwise you're vulnerable for so called **SQL-Injection Attacks**

Comment: Thanks mate, it was long ago so I managed to solve this but thanks anyway and it's good to keep it here so people can learn from it. and big thank for the sqli advice :)